# classify the plane projective curve $C\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ defined by $X^n+Y^n-Z^n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, riemannian-geometry

***Classify the plane projective curve $C\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ defined by $X^n+Y^n-Z^n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$.***

I need to know how the aforementioned curve behaves when $n$ is even or odd, if it is rational or of what type it is. I know that the palne projective curve $X^2+Y^2=Z^2$ is rational, so if $n$ is even, the curve mentioned in the question will be rational or what is it? What happens when $n$ is odd? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: what's the genus of this curve?

Comment: @KReiser The genus of this curve is $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$, which means that?

Comment: What's the genus of $\Bbb P^1$? Can two curves with different genuses be isomorphic?

Comment: @KReiser 
The genus of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $0$, They can not be isomorphic! What more can I say?

Comment: @KReiser 
So, could I say then that this curve is not the sphere of riemman? Then what is?

Comment: What more do you want to say? Are you working over $\mathbb{C}$?